# Easily switching ConnectionStrings on publish to Azure

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, azure, connection-string

I'm currently building an Azure Web Role. I am testing this project against a local database server on `localhost`. Then, when confident that the project is working, I publish it to Staging on Windows Azure.

However, I also have to remember to change the connection string to point to the live SQL server on SQL Azure before deploying, and then change it back to `localhost` afterwards.

Is there any nice way to automate this, or perhaps a different process to take to avoid the issue altogether? For example is there a way to have a configuration file for Azure that isn't updated with every deploy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just referencing the machine name and whether or not I was using Azure, dynamically switching the ConnectionString I referenced accordingly.