# How to get connection string out of Azure KeyVault?

Tags: c#, azure, security, connection-string, azure-keyvault

A hypothetical web-site currently connects using:

```
public SqlConnection CreateConnection()
{
   DbConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
   connection.ConnectionString = GetConnectionString();
   connection.Open();

   return connection;
}
```

Where the magical connection string is stored in `web.config`:

```
String GetConnectionString()
{
   //Get the connection string info from web.config
   ConnectionStringSettings cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"];

   if (cs == null)
      throw new Exception("Could not locate DB connection string");

   return cs.ConnectionString;
}
```

Now i'd like to move the connection string out of the web.config file into Azure KeyVault. How do you retrieve anything out of the Azure key vault?

```
String GetConnectionString()
{
   //Get the connection string info from Azure KeyVault
   String connectionString = GetAzureSecret("dbConnectionString");

   if (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(connectionString)
      throw new Exception.Create("Could not connection string of Azure Key Vault");

   return connectionString;
}
```

Except i just made up the easy-to-use Azure API. What is the *actual* api?

### Untested attempt

```
string GetAzureSecret(string key)
{
    KeyVaultClient vault = new KeyVaultClient();
    vault.OnAuthenticate += VaultClientAuthenticate;

    var sec = await vault.GetSecretAsync(Key);
    return sec.Value;
}

public static async Task<string> VaultClientAuthenticate(string authority, string resource, string scope)
{
   String clientID = "8675209";
   String clientSecret = "correct battery horse pencil";

   var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
   ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientID, clientSecret);
   AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred);

   if (result == null)
      throw new Exception("Could not acquire token");

   return result.AccessToken;
}
```

### Bonus Reading

- [MSDN Forums: Storing sql connection string passwords in Key Vault for my Cloud Services](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/56bed4bd-6320-4f1f-9af5-556ae91bdf0f/storing-sql-connection-string-passwords-in-key-vault-for-my-cloud-services?forum=AzureKeyVault)
- [How to properly store connection strings in Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40706406/how-to-properly-store-connection-strings-in-azure)
- [Easily switching ConnectionStrings on publish to Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997903/easily-switching-connectionstrings-on-publish-to-azure?rq=1)

Comment: Are you referring to Azure KeyVault?  Would https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-use-from-web-application help?

Comment: @CtrlDot Yes indeed; changed lingo from store to vault.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> What is the actual api?

We could use the [GetSecret API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getsecret) to get value.

**Preparation:**

[Registry Azure Active Directory application and assign Role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application)

**Steps:**

1.Create KeyVault and add secret from Azure portal

[image]

2.Config Access policy

[image]

3.Get Access token

```
 var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId);
            ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(appId, secretKey);
            var tokenResponse =await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://vault.azure.net", clientCredential);
            var accessToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;
            return accessToken;
```

**Note**: The resource for Keyvault is `https://vault.azure.net`

4.Test with Fiddler

[image]

**We also can do that easily with SDK:**

1.Create a console project and a Utils.cs file

```
public static string EncryptSecret { get; set; }
        static string appId = "Application ID";
        static string secretKey = "Secert key";
        static string tenantId = "TenantId";

        public static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string azureTenantId,string azureAppId,string azureSecretKey)
        {

            var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId);
            ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(appId, secretKey);
            var tokenResponse =await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://vault.azure.net", clientCredential);
            var accessToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;
            return accessToken;
        }
```

2.Add the follow code in the main function and test it.

[image]

packages.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Hyak.Common" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Common" version="2.0.4" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Common.Dependencies" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.9" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" version="1.0.168" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.14" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="3.13.9" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.22" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

We also can get more information from CtrlDot mentioned [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-use-from-web-application).

Answer (score 39):

### August 2020 update

There's now a low-ceremony way to call Key Vault from App Service with zero custom code via Key Vault references.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references

App Setting example that populates value from Key Vault:

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/ec96f02080254f109c51a1f14cdb1931)
```

If you don't want the version identifier:

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/)
```

---

You need to setup Managed Identity first between your App Service instance and Key Vault to be able to use Key Vault references.

I have nothing against Key Vault (i think it's a great product!), however i can't help myself but think you are overengineering this.

I would simply use the built-in [**Application Settings** functionality in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure):

> #### Connection strings
>
> For .NET apps, these connection strings are injected into your .NET configuration connectionStrings settings at runtime, **overriding existing entries where the key equals the linked database name.**

Web App → Application Settings → Connection Strings → Add a Connection String and name it `db`.

```cs
String GetConnectionString()
{
   // Get the Connection String from Application Settings (App Service) 
   // with graceful fallback to web.config
   string cs = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString;

   if (cs == null)
      throw new Exception("Could not locate DB connection string");

   return cs;
}
```

[What's the difference between the WebConfigurationManager and the ConfigurationManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698157/whats-the-difference-between-the-webconfigurationmanager-and-the-configurationm)

#### May 2018 update:

Since [Managed Service Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/overview) became a thing, acquiring an access token no longer demands secrets (service principal credentials) being stored in your service to access Key Vault, which is a much better proposition. Here's a Node.js sample just to spice up this answer a little bit:

```javascript
// Get an access token from Managed Service Identity
// on an Azure IaaS VM
async function getAccessTokenWithMSI() {
  let msi = await axios.get('http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token',
    {
      params: {
        'api-version': '2018-02-01',
        'resource': 'https://vault.azure.net'
      },
      headers: {
        'Metadata': 'true'
      },
      timeout: 2000
    });

  return msi.data.access_token;
}
```

and then:

```
// Get a secret from Key Vault
async function getSecret(accessToken, secretUrl) {
  let response;
  try {
    response = await axios.get(secretUrl,
      {
         params: { 'api-version': '2016-10-01' },
         headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
         timeout: 3000
      });
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log('\nError calling Key Vault:,
        e.response.status, e.response.statusText, e.response.data);
  }
  console.log('\nGet Secret response from Key Vault: ',
      JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 4));

  return response.data;
}
```

Comment: You solved my problem, but Tom answered the question as asked. So he had to get the accept. But you get an upvote.

Comment: I'm struggling with the `@Microsoft` syntax. I tried putting that into my code, but VS 2022 complained, asking if there's a missing assembly. I'm guessing there is, but even following the Microsoft Learn link you provided, didn't help me.

Comment: The @ syntax only works in App Settings in Azure App Service, it will not work locally.

Answer (score 13):

For .net Core and already having Azure Key Vault in place. Now it's extremely easy. Let's assume your connection string is in your appsettings.json:

```
{
   "ConnectionStrings": {
      "MyDatabase": "server=127.0.0.1;port=5678;database=mydb;user=FullMontyBurns;password=hunter2"
   } 
}
```

And you do your setup in `Startup.cs`:

```
string connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDatabase");
```

In Azure Key Vault, create a secret:

- **Name:** `ConnectionStrings--MyDatabase`
- **Value:** `server=127.0.0.1;port=5678;database=mydb;user=FullMontyBurns;password=hunter2`

[image]

The `IConfiguration.GetConnectionString("MyDatabase")` now takes the value from the Key Vault.

Comment: That password is just asterisks for me... :p

Comment: @kloarubeek I am getting the error as IConfiguration does not contains the definition for GetConnectionString. I am using as below in my code. When I am reading from appsettings it works fien but when I am doing the same via keyvault it gives error.



services.AddDbContext<ConnectionStringModel>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection")));

Answer (score 2):

Others have already provided great answers with context about how to integrate with a web app or Azure Function, but here are the definitive references for getting started with the Key Vault secrets SDK.

[.NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets/README.md)

[Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-security-keyvault-secrets/README.md)

[JavaScript](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/keyvault-secrets/README.md)

[Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-secrets/README.md)